# .pro file in BlackBerry 10 development

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am learning BlackBerry 10 apps development and referring BlackBerry's documentation for this . I have downloaded their sample apps but in those projects I have seen the following code in .pro file .

```
    TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = addressbook

CONFIG += qt warn_on debug_and_release cascades

INCLUDEPATH += ../src

SOURCES += ../src/.cpp

HEADERS += ../src/.hpp ../src/.h

LIBS += -lbbpim

lupdate_inclusion {
SOURCES += ../assets/.qml }

device {
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o.le-v7
    TEMPLATE = lib
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -fvisibility=hidden -mthumb
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o.le-v7-g
}
}

simulator {
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o-g
}
}

OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.obj
MOC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.moc

RCC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc

UI_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.ui

suredelete.target = sureclean

suredelete.commands = $(DEL_FILE) $${MOC_DIR}/; $(DEL_FILE) $${RCC_DIR}/; $(DEL_FILE) $${UI_DIR}/

suredelete.depends = distclean

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += suredelete

TRANSLATIONS = \
$${TARGET}_en_GB.ts \
$${TARGET}_fr.ts \
$${TARGET}_it.ts \
$${TARGET}_de.ts \
$${TARGET}_es.ts \
$${TARGET}.ts
```

So when I found the information about .pro file the have mentioned only that this file is used to include different bps library and given only code like this ---

```
LIBS += -lbbpim.
```

And when we create any project theres default code in .pro file like this---

```
APP_NAME = CPPLink

CONFIG += qt warn_on cascades10

include(config.pri)
```

So I am not getting what's the remaining code in their sample apps in .pro file.

Can anyone tell me ?

Answer (score 1):

The PRO file you're looking at is from an earlier version of the IDE than you have currently installed. The functions performed by the mission lines have been moved to a different location, probably for clarity.

Comment: yeah, the .pri file

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer this is probably to see the qmake documentation here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html

The remaining code in that profile does things like setup different targets (device vs simulator and debug vs release). Each one of those curly braced blocks is basically an if statement, i.e. if this build is a debug build then set these options.

There's lots more you can do with a .pro file, I would suggest reading the doc, it's not very long.

Answer (score 0):

.pro file means:

1. Project settings of your app
2. It lists libraries that your app links

what you seen in sample apps are not necessary..
(i.e)LIBS += -lbbpim.  like this is only necessary to create apps..